# how reduce the memory usage of canvas in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, optimization, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement a feature in our project which will trigger the mobile camera when pressing a capture button from mobile browser, it will append the captured image as canvas to html page, but if we capture more than 2 image, the browser get's restart automatically and showing memory low warning. Please let me know is there any way to optimize the canvas size?.

Note:
I have tested only in mobile chrome.

I'm attaching the sample code below

html code:

```
<input type="file"  id="camera" accept="image/*" capture> 
<div id="MediaOutput"></div>
```

javascript:

```
    var storedMediaList=[];
    var mobile_picture = document.querySelector("#camera");
    mobile_picture.onchange = function () {
      var file = mobile_picture.files[0];
      storedMediaList.push({id:(Math.floor(Math.random()*90000)+10000),data:file});
      drawImage();
    };

    function drawImage()
    {
          $(".rc").remove().empty();
          $("#MediaOutput").html("");
          $("#MediaOutput").html("<div class='mediaWrapper'></div>");
          storedMediaList.forEach(function(row,index,array)
          {

            $(".mediaWrapper").append("<div style='float:left;' class='ir' id='c"+row.id+"' class='pic'><div media-id="+row.id+" class='close-image' id='close-image' style='width:24px;background:url(images/close.png) no-repeat;height:25px;cursor:pointer;'></div><canvas id='cv"+row.id+"'></canvas> </div>");


            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
              var dataURL = e.target.result,
              c = document.querySelector("#cv"+row.id),
              ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
              img = new Image();

              img.onload = function() {
                c.width = img.width;
                c.height = img.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
              };

              img.src = dataURL;
           };

           reader.readAsDataURL(row.data);
       });


       function resizeImage(img, percentage) {
            var coeff = percentage/100,
            width = $(img).width(),
            height = $(img).height();

            return {"width": width*coeff, "height": height*coeff}           
       }
       $('.ir canvas').each(function(){

        var newDimensions = resizeImage( this, 70);
        this.style.width = newDimensions.width + "px";
        this.style.height = newDimensions.height + "px";
      });


      var width = 0;
      $('#MediaOutput .mediaWrapper div').each(function() {
       width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
      });
      $('#MediaOutput .mediaWrapper').css('width', width + "px");
   }
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: One thing I noticed: when you change `img = new Image();` to `var img = new Image();`, you will limit the scope of the `img` variable, so it is cleaned up sooner. I think this applies to some other variables as well.

Comment: @GolezTrol, Thank you for your suggestion :). But is that make huge memory problem?

Comment: Just asking, is there any reason to capture more than 1 image? Could you not store just one image which will get replaced by the new `camera photo`.

Comment: I don't know, but it's worth testing. Images in general are large and consume a lot of memory. A jpg image is compressed, but in memory it is treated as a bitmap image and consumes much more memory (up to 4 bytes per pixel!), so it might certainly help a little.

Comment: @Canvas, Actaully we want to capture 5 images, now it is storing in indexedDB as a blob object.

Comment: You could avoid storing the files + calling for each of them the FileReader by storing only the dataURL. Also, probably a typo when copy/pasting, but `dataURL`in the FR is undefined, should be `this.result`. GolezTrol is right, you are defining `c`, `ctx`, and `img` as global variables, scope them into your onload function. Shouldn't `$('.ir canvas')` be instead `$('.ir > canvas')` ? And for unrelated reasons, you should avoid setting canvas size with CSS.

Comment: 1) Camera resolution can be very high. So the image size can be quite huge. You might consider lowering that resolution at some point, especially since every pixels won't show on the device screen. 2) By copying the image on a canvas, you double the amount of memory required, and even triple it since almost every canvas implement double buffering. => Consider the canvas as a (lower-resolution) view on the image.

Comment: for a 5MP image, the memory required is 5M*3=15M, then it's probably doubled or tripled, so, 30-45M / image. and then, for 2 images 60-90M. Thats quite a lot. Try capturing in a lower resolution. such as 720 pixels wide. They will show up fine on a 2160p screen fine. Our eyes won't notice the glitch probably. like for a 960*720 image, memory usage is 2.7MB and even after multiplying with 3, it stays 8.1MB. This way, 5 images should consume 40 something MB, which should be allocated i think. you may also considering capturing at full res then resize just for display